# How to aggregate data from inner objects in MongoDb?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have the following model: Thre are `incidents`. Every `incident` has `time frames` and every `time frame` has `objects` that were present in this `time frame`. There can be **thousands** of frames in each incident.

```
Incident 
{
 Id: "incident 1"
 IncidetntFrames: [
  {
   Objects: [
    {
      id: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   Objects: [
    {
      id: 1
    },
    {
      id: 3
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I store Incidents in MongoDb database. I want to get a summary: Select **distinct** `objects` count that took part in each incident. In this case it would be `3` (1,2,3) - 3 is duplicated.

I tried to do it this way (C# LINQ):

```
_mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Incident>("Incident").AsQueryable()
    .Select(incident => new IncidentDto {
        Id = incident.Id;
        ObjectsCount = incident
            .IncidentFrames
            .SelectMany(received => received
                .Objects
                .Select(dto => dto.Id))
            .Distinct())
            .Count()
    });
```

And than I get an error:

> The method SelectMany is not supported in the expression tree

The solution I came up with is to denormalize data and store `objects` count as a number in `incident`.

This brings quite interesting problem to my mind. Suppose the application has already been on production and now I decided I need objects count. I would have to make some kind of migration to calculate this value and add it to existing records.

How to do this database side? I have no experience in NoSQL yet, so my thinking can be clouded with SQL-like apprach. Maybe this architecture is totally wrong?

Comment: I am not sure how to do this in `C#` but this can be easily done in `MongoDB` using `$aggregate`

Comment: "(1,2,3) - 3 is duplicated". is 3 or 1 duplicated ?

Comment: Can you try `_mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Incident>("Incident").AsQueryable().Select(inciden‌​t => incident.IncidetntFrames.Objects.id).Distinct().Count();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one thing that you can do here is project your query first to load only the data that you need and later process that data using Linq to Objects:

```
var query = _mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Incident>("Incident")
                          .Aggregate()
                          .Project(i=>new{Id= i.Id,
                                          ObjectIds= i.IncidentFrames.Select(f=>f.Objects.Select(o=>o.Id))}).ToList();

var result = query.Select(e => new IncidentDto { Id=e.Id, ObjectsCount = e.ObjectIds.SelectMany(l => l).Distinct().Count() });
```

Maybe there is a better way to do it using [aggregations](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) but that was the best solution that I could find.

### Update

I found another solution where you do the same but from database side:

```
 var Grouping = new BsonDocument { { "_id", "$Id" }, { "ObjectIds", new BsonDocument("$addToSet", "$ObjectIds") } };
 var query = collection.Aggregate()
                       .Project(i => new { i.Id, ObjectIds = i.IncidentFrames.Select(f => f.Objects.Select(o => o.Id)) })
                       .Unwind(a => a.ObjectIds)
                       .Unwind(e => e["ObjectIds"])
                       .Group<IncidentDTO>(Grouping)
                       .ToList();
```

The only is you need to change your DTO a little bit to this:

```
public class IncidentDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int[] ObjectIds { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't want to get the object ids and you want just the objects count (as your original DTO), then you can get the length of `ObjectIds` array using [$size](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) aggregation operator. If you DTO is like this:

```
public class IncidentDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ObjectsCount{ get; set; }
}
```

You could do the following:

```
 var Grouping = new BsonDocument { { "_id", "$Id" }, { "ObjectIds", new BsonDocument("$addToSet", "$ObjectIds") } };
 var projection = new BsonDocument { { "_id", "$_id" }, { "ObjectsCount", new BsonDocument("$size", "$ObjectIds") } };

 var query = collection.Aggregate()
                       .Project(i => new { i.Id, ObjectIds = i.IncidentFrames.Select(f => f.Objects.Select(o => o.Id)) })
                       .Unwind(a => a.ObjectIds)
                       .Unwind(e => e["ObjectIds"])
                       .Group(Grouping)
                       .Project<IncidentDTO>(projection).ToList();
```

Comment: but wouldn't that do the Distinct in memory ?